# JAX-WS : class not found

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am not well versed with Java. Here is the webservice, I am trying to implement - a basic example and I am facing compilation error.
I am not sure what am I missing here.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
package com.joshis1.jaxws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface IwebServiceInterface {
@WebMethod String sayHello(String name);
}
```

Next, implementing the interface

```
package com.joshis1.jaxws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.joshis1.jaxws")
public class webServiceImpl implements IwebServiceInterface {
    @Override
     public  String sayHello(String name)
     {
        return "Hello Shreyas " +  name;
     }
}
```

Next, the main class to publish the endpoint

```
package com.joshis1.publisher;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import com.joshis1.jaxws.*;

public class WebServicePublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/webservice/helloworld", new webServiceImpl());

    }

}
```

Next, very basic question - Do I need to install a web server here?

Comment: You do need to have some JAX-WS implementation in your classpath.

Comment: Actually he is pointing his endpoint interface to a package 'com.joshis1.jaxws' instead of pointing to the interface

Comment: @Prawn Hongs, here is a link to you take a look: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing your `endpointInterface` to your package:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.joshis1.jaxws")
```

It needs to reference your interface:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.joshis1.jaxws.IwebServiceInterface")
```

It is very important to look on what the error is saying

> **class:com.joshis1.jaxws** could not be found